# How to schedule report in Automation studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

How to schedule report (standard/Custom) in Automation studio ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you some any research at all? Please **[edit]** your post to demonstrate that you have made some effort.

Comment: Yes as Adrian Larson said,  we need more information as there are multiple ways to accomplish this...

Comment: Hi Dorjee - did we manage to answer this, or is more information needed? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go into email studio => interactions => report, and there you need to define your report definition first, prior for you to be able to reference it in automation studio. 
The "Report" definition is not part of the new automation studio activity interface yet, so you need to go into via email studio at this point in time. Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only works with Email reports. Could not get this to work with SMS reports