# To run a report on transnational Emails and Marketing Cloud Emails send out from Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am new to M.C. I have a requirement to create a report to seperate transactional emails and M.C emails send out from M.C. 
for the report type am using Discover options.

Comment: Do you have Data Extract > Tracking  Extract enabled in your account?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Account Send Summary Standard report.
This report can be generated from Email Studio->Tracking Menu or
Analytics Builder->Reports.

[Account Send Summary Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_account_send_summary_report.htm&type=5)

Comment: do you know if we can schedule this report  instead of launching it manually ? thanks

Comment: @AshBringer Yes we can schedule this report. Refer to this post on how to schedule a report. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158929/how-to-schedule-report-in-automation-studio